# What is the alternate of SVG fill attribute in vector drawable

Tags: android, drawable, android-vectordrawable

I have converted .svg file into VectorDrawable .xml file, but .svg file uses fill attribute which is not get converted into .xml file.
Actually fill method is not supported by this [Converter](http://a-student.github.io/SvgToVectorDrawableConverter.Web/) which i am using.

if you have any idea about how to render svg images into android vectorDrawable as it is please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: r u using Android Studio?

Comment: @Onkar Nene : Yes, I am using Android Studio 2.1

Comment: Good. check my answer, hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
android:fillColor="#FFC524" // use your own color code
```

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio have inbuilt tool call **Vector Asset Studio**. Using this tool you can create vector drawables from local **.SVG** files or **Material icons**.

Vector drawables are added in Support Library **23.2**, so for using vector drawables and supported in all API's you should add something like this in your `build.gradle` (App level)-

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
}
```

For creating vector drawables using Vector assets studio use foll. instructions -

**To start Vector Asset Studio:**

1) In Android Studio, open an Android **app** project.

2) In the Project window, select the **Android view**.

3) Right-click the **res** folder and **select New > Vector Asset**.

For reference and more details check the link below :

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html#running

Hope it will help :)